# How to post login api using AFNetworking?

Tags: ios

I am stuck in my code from last three days. I add login api in my code and when i hit it i got strange behavior from server side. please look at my code.

```
- (IBAction)btnSignInPressed:(id)sender {

if (_txtFieldEmail.text.length >0 ) {
    if (_txtFieldPassword.text.length >0) {
            Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
            NetworkStatus status = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];
            if (status) {
                [SVProgressHUD setOffsetFromCenter:UIOffsetMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, 60)];

                [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
                NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@&deviceToken=testdata",_txtFieldEmail.text,self.txtFieldPassword.text];
                NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[urlString length]];
                NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];
                NSString *url = @"http://qa.networc.in:1336/api/users/app/login";
                [req setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
                [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
                [req setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
                [req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
                [req setHTTPBody:[urlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:
                 ^(NSURLResponse *reponse , NSData *data, NSError *error){
                     NSError *errre1;
                    dictLogin=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&errre1];
                    NSLog(@"result is%@ :",dictLogin);
                     [user setObject:[dictLogin objectForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"email"];

                     if ([dictLogin objectForKey:@"email"]) {
                         [SVProgressHUD dismiss  ];
                         MainVC *mainVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainvc"];
                         [self presentViewController:mainVC animated:NO completion:nil];
                     }else {
                         [SVProgressHUD dismiss  ];
                         logInAlertView.tag = 1;
                         logInAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"SignIn !" message:[dictLogin objectForKey:@"msg"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                         logInAlertView.tag = 1;

                         [logInAlertView show];
                     }

                }];
            } else {
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Internet Alert" message:@"Please check your internet." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
            }
        }else{
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password Alert !" message:@"Please enter the password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    }
}else{
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email Alert !" message:@"Please enter email." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    _txtFieldPassword.text = @"";
}
```

}

When I hit this code on button click, I get this output in the console.Response from Server :

`{"code":400,"status":0,"acType":"","user":null,"message":"Oops! Wrong password."}`.

I entered correct email and password but I don't know why I get this error.

Comment: your coding is fine , good and correct , check once in your backend,if you have doubt add static data and check

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks for your response sir, i need to ask one question sir, if my code is fine than why this block of code not executed. if ([dictLogin objectForKey:@"email"]) {
                         [SVProgressHUD dismiss  ];
                         MainVC *mainVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainvc"];
                         [self presentViewController:mainVC animated:NO completion:nil];
                     }

Comment: if i print user using nslog than get null value sir

Comment: can you print the response once  NSLog(@"result is%@ :",dictLogin);

Comment: it means you get empty value , thats y the condition  does not call bro

Comment: yes sir pleas look at this diclogin result 2016-04-28 10:39:55.718 Juststart[1087:25336] result is{
    acType = "";
    code = 400;
    message = "Oops! Wrong password.";
    status = 0;
    user = "<null>";
} :

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110451/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-sandeep-tomar).

Comment: how will i print email value in my console?

Comment: your problem is resolved or not bro

Comment: no sir not yet, backend developers says these are correct credentials

Comment: ok generate new user and check once bro

Comment: ok sir tried to resolve it, i am sure problem from backend